# Import two column sql table with PHP PDO to an array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm using PHP PDO to access a sql database.  There's a table with just two columns (ID and VALUE).  I want to read that table into an array such that

```
$array[ID]=VALUE
```

I know how I can do it manually with a for loop or while loop going through one by one… but I was wondering if there's any better way of doing it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @MarcB that's what I have been using, but it returns an array of arrays instead of just one array.

Comment: I wouldn't call it any "better" though. "syntax sugar" rather it is

Comment: it is not about "using". It is rather about *reading*. the link provided

Comment: that's to be expected. if you get multiple rows of data from your query, fetchAll will give you an array of arrays, each sub-array representing one row of data. if you want to do your own x[id]= value, then you'll have to do a loop.

Comment: I am sorry, it is not on that page, but on different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.fetch-key-pair) constant

```
$sql  = "select id, username from users limit 10";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew there had to be something like that.